# Error in Parse PFLoginViewController

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Trying to integrate the default login provided by Parse.com
Getting some error.Can anyone help me in this.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `ParseUI` framework is missing. Go to the [download page](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/releases), download this framework and add it to you project.

Comment: I have added all the parse frameworks using Pod so these frameworks should be added in the process or I have to add them manually again?

Comment: Did you open the xcworkspace file created by cocoapods after that ?

Comment: When you use cocoapods, it creates a YourProject.xcworkspace file next to you YourProject.xcodeproj file. You should use the xcworkspace file from now on to open your project.

Comment: In your target settings, what's under "Linked Frameworks and libraries" ? Also what does your podfile look like ?

Comment: Pod files are coming in red

Comment: No, the podfile is the file at the root of your project in which you specify the installed pods

Comment: Oh there target 'DemoParse' do
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'
pod 'Parse'
end

Comment: As I said, you are missing the ParseUI framework. add the line `pod 'ParseUI'`

Comment: Thanks bro for the help its working now,will add one more thing we have to set the viewController's class PFLogInViewController

Comment: Ya was a question but got the answer now.Btw thanks for the help.Its working perfectly now.